# Codeigniter application index.php removed randomly in url on amazon EC2 clound server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, centos

I am working on a web application. I am facing a very strange issue while navigating the app on cloud amazon EC2 instance 1 that it randomly choose some links and when I click on those links it is redirecting me to page not found or sometime home page or sometime on login page. Although session still persist.

Previously I have added the `.htaccess` file to removed the `index.php` from the urls but after noticing this issue I have revert the changes but my `re_write_mode` still enabled in apache `httpd.conf` file and `.htaccess` file reside on root of the application with commented code.

Apache configuration mentioned below.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would be running in that problem from what you posted...here is the .htaccess file I use at the root of all of my CI projects to remove index.php from the URL

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Nothing looks extremely out of the ordinary regarding your apache config.  I would say that it sounds more like a problem with your "routes."  Do you have any custom routes setup in your app?

Also, did you change your $config['index_page'] and/or $config['base_url'] in your config file?

Comment: thanks for your response.

please check my config file setting as you mentioned above $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/[application_name]/"; 
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Also having issue of redirecting some pages to login page although session is there. Dont know why this happen
because same application with setting and configuration is running perfect on local system but having issues on 
amazon clound ec2.

Comment: currently I am facing issue of consistently redirecting to login page.

Comment: It sounds like it is probably a problem in your logic somewhere then.  It's hard to know without seeing how you are checking if someone is "logged in", etc...